# System-sleep script not executed

Tags: scripts, suspend, systemd

I have a simple script `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/start_my_lock` and it wouldn't run when the system is suspended, I am trying to make i3lock my default lock

```sh
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
  pre)
    scrot /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png
    convert /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png -scale 10% -scale 1000% /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png
    convert /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png /home/jappatel/Pictures/Icons/lock.png -gravity center -composite -matte /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png
    i3lock -i /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png
    rm /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Try using the full path to your home directory.

Comment: Did you make the script file executable? What's the output of `ls -l /lib/systemd/system-sleep/start_my_lock`? Also `~` probably doesn't do what you intend here because the script is executed by the system user. You should specify the name of the user to whom the home directory belongs, e. g. `~jaypatel/test`. Btw, custom hook scripts likely belong somewhere in `/etc` and not `/lib`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster according to man page for systemd-suspend.service, the path is correct and also adding the full path fixed it so the script is being executed for sure, but when I replace this with 'path/to/script' I want to execute it doesn't execute it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried exactly according to your comment. Could you please [edit] your question and explain your actions and their results as clearly as possible? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have edited my post -- Thank You for help

Comment: Could you please insert the commands `exec &>/tmp/start_my_lock.log` and `date; id; echo "$@"` (in that order) near the beginning of the script? That will produce a log file `/tmp/start_my_lock.log` with some useful info about the execution environment and potential error messages of the invoked programs.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution,** I had to run the script on my local user instead of root

```
su jappatel -c <command>
```

and also run and also specify the display using

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

my final script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
  pre)
    su jappatel -c "
    DISPLAY=:0 scrot /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png;
    convert /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png -scale 10% -scale 1000% /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png;
    convert /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png /home/jappatel/Pictures/Icons/lock.png -gravity center -composite -matte /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png;
    DISPLAY=:0 i3lock -i /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png;
    rm /home/jappatel/tmp/screen.png"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools that rely on a display server or a user session like `scrot` or `i3lock` don't work from background system scripts because they can't find the display server and/or user session.

### Solution

You need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable before you invoke these tools with either

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:0 <COMMAND>
```

If for whatever reason `DISPLAY` should have a different value adjust it as suitable. You can check the *current* value from inside a graphical session with `echo "$DISPLAY"`.

For more info on a very similar issue see [How to start a GUI application from cron?](/q/514167/175814)

### Testing

You can test your scripts to run without session-related environment variables if you prefix their invocation with `env -i`, e. g.

```
env -i /lib/systemd/system-sleep/start_my_lock
```

which empties the environment variable list.

Comment: What's the output of `echo "$DISPLAY"` in a regular graphical session? Did you make the script file executable? What's the output of `ls -l /lib/systemd/system-sleep/start_my_lock`?

Comment: Hey @David thank you so much for you help I was able to get it to work. I have added my final script to my question, and sorry I can't upvote your solution